# Is a debuggable android application exploitable from another application?

Tags: android

I know that if an application set debuggable to true in the manifest a user with physical access can debug the application and get access to the private directory of the debuggable application.

But is it possible from another installed app to exploit the debuggable application or is it only exploitable with physical access ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

First let me clarify "physical access" that you mention. It's adb shell (which can be accessible over TCP as well, if configured so; but normally it requires access to USB, and physical user to use touch screen), and for debuggable apps, one can use `run-as` to change their UID to that of the app (and do anything as if they were an app). `run-as` is limited to root and `shell` GID, so plain apps should not have access to it.

There might be mechanisms similar to `run-as`, but one would expect similar security restrictions.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I thought... And backup enabled works the same way I guess ?

Comment: Similar idea. `shell` is quite powerful - it can also listen to/inject input events, read logs of any app. I treat it as more privileged as an app, but less as `system`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Have a good day !